# Stack Exchange MultiCollider/SuperDropdown doesn't dropdown on Moderator History page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderation

On the History page in the mod tools, the SE multicollider doesn't drop down, instead it purely acts as a button to the http://stackexchange.com address.

So this:

[image: Stack Exchange Supercollider being clicked]

Takes us to this:

[image: Stack Exchange Page]

It does work perfectly fine* on the other pages, and the issue is not present on Meta Arqade:

[image: Meta Arqade - Supercollider dropdown]

<sub>* This does occasionally happen on other (not mod-specific) pages when the page does not load fully before clicking the supercollider, however on the History page this is occurring all the time - even when the page has completely finished loading.</sub>

It is occurring in the latest versions of Firefox/Chrome that I've tested and Chrome on Android that Ash has tested.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome on my Android phone, if that helps any.

Comment: Repro on the main site but not on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! Cross-posting [from a similar thread on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336633/1114):

> A quick-fix suppressing the errors from absentee notice rows, to prevent the rest of the page from being broken, will be included in the next build.